# hibernate - building a query across @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I've got 2 classes:

```
@Entity
public class Basic {
    private String a;
    @OneToMany
    private List<Element> elements;
}

@Entity
public class Element {
    private String b;
}
```

what I'm trying to do is create a `Predicate` that tests for if a `Basic` has an `Element` where `b` is some value (say `b.equals("hello world")`).
I'm constrained to implement this method:

```
public Predicate testBasic(String elementValue, Root<Basic> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb);
```

thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know HQL usually has access to submembers torugh the dot operator.

Have you tried:

```
where basics.elements.b LIKE %xxx%
```

Else the solution is to use a JOIN

```
from basics b right join elements e on e.fk_b = b.id where e.b like %str%
```

Comment: Can you write a code example for the method? Also, I'd prefer if possible to work with the criteria - is there a way?